Eigen matrix multiplication is much less efficient than for loop traversal
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    const int num_points = 300000000;

    Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> init_points(num_points, 3);
    Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> transformed_points(num_points, 3);

    std::mt19937 rng(42); 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(-100.0f, 100.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i)
    {
        init_points(i, 0) = dist(rng); // x
        init_points(i, 1) = dist(rng); // y
        init_points(i, 2) = dist(rng); // z
    }

    float theta = 3.14159265358 / 4; // pi/4
    Eigen::Matrix3f rotation;
    rotation = Eigen::AngleAxisf(theta, Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ());

    Eigen::Vector3f translation(10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);

    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //transformed_points = init_points * rotation;   //uncomment this line to use the Matrix multiply version
    //transformed_points.rowwise() += translation.transpose(); //uncomment this line to use the Matrix multiply version

    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i) //comment this for loop to use the Matrix multiply version
    {
        Eigen::Vector3f v = init_points.row(i).transpose();
        v = rotation * v;
        v += translation;
        transformed_points.row(i) = v.transpose();
    }

    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> duration_ms = end_time - start_time;
    std::cout << "total consume: " << duration_ms.count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "first 5 points:(x,y,z)" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "("<< transformed_points(i, 0) << ","<< transformed_points(i, 1) << ", " << transformed_points(i, 2) << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

I am currently performing a coordinate transformation on an object obtained through point cloud sampling. I need to rotate a set of points first, and then translate them to obtain a transformed point cloud.
This point cloud data contains a total of 300,000,000 points, and I am using Eigen's dynamic arrays for storage.
The code above is a test example where I initialize 300,000,000 points with random numbers and then perform a rotation and translation operation. This code includes both a for-loop traversal version and a matrix multiplication version. To use matrix multiplication, you just need to uncomment the two lines I’ve commented out and comment out the for-loop part.
Here is a comparison of the time consumed by the for-loop traversal and matrix multiplication versions:
1. For the rotation and translation operations, I tried multiplying all 300,000,000 points by the rotation matrix directly and then adding the translation vector. This operation takes about 2044ms on my i7-13700k CPU.
2. I wrote a for-loop to traverse each point and apply rotation and translation one by one. The total time is only about 600ms.
I know Eigen utilizes many CPU instruction sets to optimize matrix multiplication, and I am using the Intel ICC compiler with various SIMD and AVX optimizations enabled. Why is the for-loop traversal 3 times faster than matrix multiplication here?
In addition, is there any room for further optimization of the above code?
Could someone help analyze this? I would greatly appreciate it.
PS:I do have optimizations turned on, because with optimizations turned off the time taken is much higher than it is now. What I mean is that when I turn on optimizations the for loop is faster than doing the matrix multiplication alone

This line doesn't compile: transformed_points += translation. Transpose(). Did you mean to write transformed_points.rowwise() += translation.transpose()?

it's possible the compiler has realised you're only use 5 of the values and is discarding the calculation of some of the rest, try using all the values, (e.g. write them to a file) and see if the result is still the same

Have a look at the generated code. The Intel ICX compiler at high levels of optimisation on the right CPU can work SIMD miracles with for loops with very little in them. My guess is that overheads dominate the Eigen timings for small matrixes and lots of points. I have seen ICX be unreasonably faster in some production code and never been able to construct a convincing MRE to demonstrate it in a toy program.

@MartinBrown So is there any room for further optimization in the above code? Because the for loop simply traverses all the points in a single thread, is there any way to further optimize it so that it can run faster?

I can reproduce the issue with GCC (full optimization, -DNDEBUG, etc). For the record: You can optimize by combining the rotation and translation into an Affine3f and apply it to the whole matrix in a single expression as described here. But it's still slow. Not sure what's wrong with that code path right now. Changing to column vectors per point or using -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_TO_ROW_MAJOR didn't help either

Yes, I tried what you said, and it didn't help.

It is hard to say. My guess is that you may already be saturating memory bandwidth but try using VTune on it and you will know for sure. That and profile directed compilation can sometimes remove bottlenecks and stalls that the (already excellent) Intel optimised code generation has accidentally created. The only way to know for sure about multi threading is to set 2 threads on different cores running flat out and measure what happens. Nothing trumps experimental data.

Part of the issue is definitely that the matrix layout is suboptimal and assigning with transposition requires temporary memory (see also: noalias()) plus multiple scans over the data. But even if I change to the better Eigen::Matrix3Xf transformed_points = t * init_points (with Affine3f t and Matrix3Xf init_points), it's still 50% slower than simply iterating over the data

Yes, I hope someone else can provide further answers.

Which of the two commented lines use how much of time in your experiment?

transformed_points = init_points * rotation;
transformed_points.rowwise() += translation. Transpose();  these tow lines use 2000ms @LajosArpad

I asked how much each line uses.

@LajosArpad  1st： 1620ms,  2nd: 270ms

So the main culprit is the first line.

How is the performance of both cases changing if you use more volatile input data, that is, the points you have very much more? Is the second approach getting much slower in that case?

@LajosArpad nothing changed, this is not the reason

@AlanBirtles: A good way to make compilers generate all the values in an array is volatile auto sink = array[argc]; - index with a runtime-variable; in theory compilers could look at the index ahead of time and only do work that leads to it, but GCC and Clang don't.  If you're looking at the asm anyway so you'd notice if they didn't make a loop, it's a handy trick that's quick to write.  Or a common technique is to sum or XOR an array and print that result.  Writing a whole array to a file is more work to write, and slower.
